# Can we add a new reason to the "Close" list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

I note that one of our moderators, gotube, has started to remind OPs, who use images of text rather than copy them out, that images cannot be read by screen readers (used by the visually impaired) and neither can the they be searched. He has started by doing a few transcriptions for newbies but also chiding the OPs who should know better.
I'm all in favour of this and have posted similar comments to image using  OPs in the past.
I'm suggesting that this could be added to the list of reasons for closing a post which are accessible to those of us with sufficient privileges. Either as one of the site specific ones or to the general list of reasons that apply to all sites, since it applies to all questions.
I've no idea how this could be achieved as it's way above my pay grade.

Comment: Aside #1: I fill in image text a few times every week for new users, who are more likely to be put off by *You-did-this-wrong-now-do-it-again*, and who might see my doing it for them as a kind, welcoming gesture. I remember appreciating those comments when I was new here. In contrast, more experienced users have almost certainly seen that kind of message around the site and will understand it's not personal, just keeping the machine ticking over on its own. If I started doing the work for these higher-rep users, they wouldn't bother doing it themselves anymore.

Answer (score 3):

While posting images of text is a problem, I don’t think it makes an interesting question out of scope for the site. Also, it is a problem that can easily be corrected by the community by transcribing the text. I don’t mean to minimize the importance of accessibility (which I advocate for often), but accessibility concerns are not a reason to close a question or delete an answer.

Closing a question should be used to prevent answers while the question is being clarified or brought into scope, not because you want to punish someone for not formatting it properly. If a post is low-effort or badly formatted, a downvote is more appropriate.

If the entire question is nothing but an image of a homework or quiz question, we already have close reasons that handle that:

> This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: Details, Please.

If the asker has included those details, but didn't want to type out the question from their book, then just let them know that images of text are discouraged, and if you feel like helping them, transcribe the text for them. You can even leave the image as part of the question so it's clear to people answering that it was transcribed correctly. If someone is repeatedly posting images of text even after it's been explained why that's a problem, downvote the question and move on.

Related discussion about the inaccessibility of images of text that you can direct people to for more information:
[Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/273494)

Comment: I don't know where I got it, but I heard that images without text descriptions were against the CoC (or something) because they aren't accessible, so they're simply not allowed and must be removed. One of the first things I learned when I took the post and I've just been following that since. I would never say that a question with an image is off-topic, but rather that it's not allowed, and should be closed until it's fixed.

Comment: @gotube There's a difference between text descriptions of images (ALT text) and images of text. There is also a big difference between practices that are discouraged and disallowed content that must be removed. You misunderstood whatever gave you the impression that images without ALT text must be removed. There is no reason to close a perfectly understandable question because you don't like the way it is formatted. In the SE system, the correct response is to edit the post.

Comment: *Closing a question should be used to prevent answers while the question is being clarified or brought into scope.* should be reminded more often.